# Use Google News Search API to display news with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, google-maps, google-news

I am trying to fetch Google news with the News Search API using AngularJS, but I am having some issues. I need help please.

Below is my HTML page where I've included  the necessary libraries AngularJS, **ngAutocomplete** and another Google Library. the **ngAutocomplete** library allows me to get basic information (such as geocoding, administrative boundaries and other geo-parameters) from the Google API, that I can then use to query the News Search API.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ngAutocomplete.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <form id="form" role="form">                 
     <input type="text" id="Autocomplete" ng-autocomplete="result1" details="details1" options="options1">
     </input-container>
     <button data-ng-click="findNews(result1)">Search</button>                                
  </form>
 <div data-ng-repeat="news in newsData">
     <img src="{{news.image.url}}}"alt="{{news.title}}">
     <h2>{{news.title}}</h2>
     <p>{{news.content}}</p>
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my **script.js**

```
(function(){ 

'use strict;'
angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAutocomplete'])

.controller('AppCtrl', ['newsService', '$scope', '$mdSidenav', function(newsService, $scope, $mdSidenav){
  $scope.toggleSidenav = function(menuId) {
    $mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
  };

 function fetchNews(result1){
    newsService.getNews(result1).then(function(data){
      $scope.location = data;
    });
  }
  fetchNews('San Francisco');

  $scope.findNews = function(result1){
    $scope.location = '';
    fetchNews(result1);
  };

}])

.factory ('newsService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){


  function getNews(result1){

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q=' + result1)
      .success(function(data){
        newsData = data.responseData.results;
        console.log(newsData);
      })
      .error(function(err){
        console.log('Error retrieving News');
        deferred.reject(err);
      });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
  return{
    getNews:getNews
  }
}])

})();
```

When I type San Francisco, and then click the search button, the app get the user input and queries the Google News Search API and then return an object.

The query returns a News object from the News Search API; I can see it on the console.log but unfortunately I cannot display them on the page using ngRepeat.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="news in newsData">
  <img src="{{news.image.url}}}"alt="{{news.title}}">
  <h2>{{news.title}}</h2>
  <p>{{news.content}}</p>
</div>
```

The full code is on Plunker http://plnkr.co/4vbaWZvcSRMGXppA5sXY or http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/eevO0F/